# How to select matching results with other random results in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all the matching results in a database table with also random results but with the matching results being at the top. With the way, I am doing now I am using two queries first one being the matching query, and if the count is zero I now select random results. I would like to do this with just one query.

Comment: Can you provide example of your case? Or maybe can show your schema?

Comment: I am making a search with filters such as min and max price, so I would not like the search to return an empty result if there is no record that matches the filter but instead returns random results and also if few records match the search filter then return the few records also with random records but matching records being at the top.

Comment: How about you just UNION (QUERY UNION QUERY) first query with your matched condition second QUERY with random one.

Comment: In this way, you don't need to write two queries instead it will be combined into one single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attempt using a UNION ALL query as follows.

```
select product_name,price
  from marketing_table
 where price >=5000 /*user supplied filter*/
   and price <=10000 /*user supplied filter*/
union all
select m.product_name,m.price
  from marketing_table m
 where not exists (select *
                     from marketing_table m1
                    where m1.price >=5000 /*user supplied filter*/
                      and m1.price <=10000 /*user supplied filter*/
                   )
```

Comment: . . You don't need `union all`, you can just use `OR` in the `where` clause.  That said, the optimize in MySQL might do a better job with your version.

Comment: Since I want both tables to return results at the same time OR won't be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from you comment, you may try something simple like this first:

```
SET @product := 'purse'; -- search term

SELECT * FROM product 
ORDER BY product_name LIKE CONCAT('%',@product,'%') DESC, price ASC;
```

This is the simplest I can think of and it could be a starting point for you.

Here's a demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/31jrR27dFJqYQQigzBqLcs/2

If this is not what you want, you have to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62768015/edit) and insert some example data with expected output. Your current question tend to be flagged as too broad and need focus/clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a UNION subquery with a LIMIT?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 0 priority, t.*
FROM first_table t
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 priority, t.*
FROM second_table t
)
ORDER BY priority
LIMIT 20
```

If you do not want to include any second_table records if first_table returns, you would need to do a subquery on the second query to confirm that no rows exist.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 0 priority, t.*
FROM first_table t
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 priority, t.*
FROM second_table t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM first_table) a
WHERE a.id IS NULL
)
ORDER BY priority
LIMIT 20
```

I think it would be possible to use the Common Table Expressions (CTE) feature in MySQL 8, if you are using that version.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html